# Akka: how to make non-blocking JDBC requests

Tags: java, jdbc, akka

I am brand new to Akka (**Java lib**) and am trying to understand if Akka can be used to make non-blocking requests to JDBC, and if so, what that it would look like. I *believe* most JDBC drivers open a socket connection and block the thread that created it until a particular JDBC response is received, and so there might not be much Akka can do to help here, but I am wondering if there is a way (perhaps through Futures or Agents?) that Akka could help improve performance, and allow the actor system to continue processing data, while an existing JDBC call is being made and awaiting a response.

I found [this article](http://noisycode.com/blog/2014/07/27/akka-and-jdbc-to-services/) which is a bit vague/cryptic, but it sounds like futures might be the key here. However that article doesn’t really show any meaningful (real-world) code examples, and so I’m still at a loss. So let’s say we have a stored procedure, `sp_make_expensive_calculation`, that normally takes 10 - 30 seconds to return a response and that is normally called via JDBC like so:

```
String makeExpensiveCalculationSql = "{call sp_make_expensive_calculation(?)}";
callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(makeExpensiveCalculationSql);
callableStatement.setInt(1, 10);

// Could take up to 30 seconds to complete.
callableStatement.executeUpdate();

int answer = callableStatement.getString(2);
```

Can Akka do anything to help here so that the actor system can continue processing data (and even make other `sp_make_expensive_calculation` calls) while we wait for the first call to return?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general pattern is to use separate [execution contexts](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/dispatch/ExecutionContext.html): one for synchronous database access via JDBC, one for reactive processing. Also see the [Akka futures documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html#Execution_Contexts).

When you create an actor system it creates its own execution context -- this is the one you use for your normal reactive processing with actors. You need to create a second execution context for the JDBC calls. You will then pass this execution context to the future factory as shown [here in the Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html#Use_Directly).

In order to be notified when the future has completed, you can (optionally) use the pipe construct (also shown in the previous link, but in the preceeding documentation section). The effect of the pipe construct is to take the return value of the future, whose type is that of the future's generic type parameter (for example, the result of your query), and post it to the specified actor's mailbox.

The code executed by the future *must not* modify or even read any mutable data owned by the initiating actor (or any actor, for that matter). You'll need to tag the result of the future so that when it arrives in the actor's mailbox the actor will be able to associate it with the initial JDBC request. Finally, your actor will eventually receive the result and you can continue to process it (subject to Akka's at-most-once delivery guarantees).

Note that you don't *have* to use two execution contexts -- one will also work, but there would be a danger of your database requests consuming all available threads in the execution context.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that the JDBC connection will block until the request is through, but if you wrap it in an asynch processor you can allow it to finish and let the main thread continue.

One way to give the requestor access to the outcome of the JDBC request is by supplying a callback that is invoked when the asynch database process is complete.

Comment: Thanks @duffymo (+1) - however I just searched the Akka docs high and low for a construct called "asynchronous processor" and I don't see any. Can you provide a code snippet, or link to the documentation where this "asynch processor" is defined? Thanks again!

Comment: "High and low"?  2nd hit from Google: https://jaxenter.com/tutorial-asynchronous-programming-with-akka-actors-105682.html

Comment: Thanks @duffymo (+1) - what was your google search for that? I ask because I am a Java developer and currently don't have the bandwidth to learn Scala as well, and would like to search for the same term/phrase but with a Java example. In other words, the code in the link you provided is completely Greek to me! Thanks again!